# Return last directory in a path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return the last directory in a path.  For instance, for the following path, I wish to return "third".  My paths always start with no slashes and end with a slash.  If the path is empty, I wish to return an empty string.

first/second/third/

Below is my attempt.  Any recommendations on a better way?

```
var path='first/second/third/';
path1=path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
path2=path1.substr(path1.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var path='first/second/third/';
var path2 = path.split('/');
path2 = path2[path2.length-2];
```

`-2` because the last one is empty because of the last slash.

Answer (score 3):

The lighter way of achieving such thing :)

```
// Remove trailing slash and split by slashes, then pick the last occurrence
path = path.replace(/\/$/, "").split("/").pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

split your way to success

```
var parts = path.split("/");
var last = parts[parts.length-1];
```

Of course, you'll need to decide what to do on `fist/path/to/last` vs. `first/path/to/last/`. Your usecases might require handling either one or both.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the path and if the last directory is undefined (because the path is empty) use an empty string:

```
var path='first/second/third/';
var parts = path.split("/");
var path1 = parts[parts.length - 2] || ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split would be better/cleaner choice here..

```
var directories = path.split("/");
var lastDir     = directories[directories.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var path='first/second/third/';
path.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1]; // return third
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function `segment` that will take a url like string and return a specific part of it (using 1 counting, not 0). So, `segment(str, 1)` return `first`, and `segment(str, 3)` returns `third`. It also includes a `trim` function to strip off nasty preceding or trailing slashes which would cause empty items in the segments array... but maybe you want those so in that case just use `return str.split...` in the segment function.

```
var trim = function (str, charset) {
    charset = charset || "\s";

    var regex = new RegExp("^[" + charset + "]+|[" + charset + "]+$", "g")
    return str.replace(regex, "");
};

var segment = function (str, offset) {
    return trim(str, '/').split('/')[offset - 1];
}
```